# Android Activity dies if executet GET on webservice

Tags: android, web-services, get

I'm trying to log in an user communicating with a RESTful webservice. While this code works fine in the eclipse Android emulator, executing it on a mobile device results in an error. More precisely, the Acitivity dies, throwing error messages that vary each time.

This is the code in my LoginActivity. The method `tryLogin(View v)` is executed when clicked on the login button:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.s_login);
    }

    public void tryLogin(View v){
        EditText un = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_li_username);
        EditText pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_li_password);

        String username = un.getText().toString();
        String password = "";

        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(pw.getText().toString().getBytes(), 0, pw.getText().toString().length());
            password = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);         
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            ToastHandler.showToast(e.getMessage(), this);
        }

        ToastHandler.writeToLog("now exevuting get");
        String url = RestHandler.REST_URL + "arg=0&un=" + username + "&pw=" + password + "&" + RestHandler.API_KEY;

        String[] response = RestHandler.executeGET(url, this);  // Line 43
        String formattedResponse = "";



        if(response != null && response[1] != null){
            ToastHandler.writeToLog(response[1]);
            if(response[0].equals("json")){

            }else{
                String temp = response[1].trim();
                formattedResponse = temp.substring(1, temp.length()-1);
            }
        }else{
            ToastHandler.showToast("Fehler beim Einloggen!", this);
        }       

        if(formattedResponse == "Livia" || formattedResponse == "Luki" || formattedResponse.equals("Maki") 
                || formattedResponse=="Nadine" || formattedResponse=="Roberto"){
            loginUser(formattedResponse);
        }else{
            ToastHandler.showToast("Falsche Benutzerangaben!", this);
        }
    }

    private void loginUser(String username){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("username", username);
        startActivity(intent);
        //finish();    
    }

}
```

The function `executeGET(...)` from RestHandler is as follows:

```
public static String[] executeGET(String url, Context context){
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response;
        String[] result = new String[2]; 

        Log.i("url", url);

        try{
            response = CLIENT.execute(get); // Line 36
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            if(entity != null){
                InputStream in = entity.getContent();
                result[1] = convertStreamToString(in, context);

                JsonElement jsonElem = new JsonParser().parse(result[1]);

                if(jsonElem.isJsonArray()) {
                    result[0] = "json";
                } else {
                    result[0] = "nok";
                }

                in.close();
            }
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e){
            ToastHandler.showToast(e.getMessage(), context);
        }catch (IOException e){
            ToastHandler.showToast(e.getMessage(), context);
        }catch (JsonSyntaxException e){
            ToastHandler.showToast(e.getMessage(), context);            
        }

        return result;
    }
```

As already mentioned, there are in particular two error messages, that are throwed:

```
(...)
W/InputDispatcher(1985): Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred
E/InputDispatcher(1985): channel '...' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
W/InputDispatcher(1985): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel
(...)
```

and

```
(...)
E/AndroidRuntime(12277): at imhotapp.schlettibusiness.rest.RestHandler.executeGET(...36)
E/AndroidRuntime(12277): at imhotapp.schlettibusiness.LoginActivity.tryLogin(...43)
(...)
```

with no particular description.

At this point, I have no idea what causes this error. When started to implement it, I considered to use an AsyncTask to process the login, but as everything worked fine in the emulator, I tried it on a mobile device too. Is this the problem? Why does such a conceptional issue works on the emulator but not on a mobile device?

Comment: Can we have the full stacktrace?

Comment: how can I extract the stacktrace from the mobile device?

Comment: There should be more lines above and below the second error you have posted.

Comment: I understand, my question is how to get the log in a kind of file instead typing all manually.

Comment: Copy and paste from logcat?

Comment: yes, but from the mobile device. Like mentioned in the question, this happens on a mobile device, not in the emulator. That's why I'm asking how to 'copy-paste' from a device

Comment: Where are you reading the logs? You should be able to see them on your computer when have the device connected with a USB cable.

Comment: Now I understand you. Since I have no USB-cable here, I cannot do usual USB-Debugging. However, using AsyncTask did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem in RestHandler.executeGET(url, this);. It execute in UI thread. Use AsyncTask or REST client pattern http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html

Comment: Dont use AsyncTask to perform network request because AsyncTask is strongly tied to the activity which has started it resulting on destroyed AsyncTask when activity is destroyed (when the orientation changes for example). You should use service pattern instead. Have a look to library such as [RESTDroid](https://github.com/PCreations/RESTDroid) that implements GoogleIO you mentionned

Answer (score 1):

As per Android guidelines, you are not supposed to do network activity on the main UI thread, else you get [`NetworkOnMainThreadException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html). This was introduced in Honeycomb. So if your emulator is Gingerbread or lower, the code will work, and if the real device is Honeycomb or higher, it will fail. Use `AsyncTask` to your benefit.